Xorg Touche configuration for 3-finger swipe is not available
Because I was not able to configure my Ubuntu touchpad speed, I installed xorg and have been trying to configure it manually. 3 finger swipe was not available, so i installed touche. Touche is causing me headaches because the swipe direction is not natural and it does not let me configure it.

